# Convert QString to QJsonArray

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt, qstring

I am trying to get an array from a QString.

I got advices online to convert the string to QJsonDocument, however, my array is empty.

```
QString string = "\"person\":\"{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}";
QJsonDocument doc1 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(string.toUtf8());

QJsonArray array = doc1.array();
```

Expected result is to get an array of QJsonValues (a QJsonArray):

```
array[0] : {"name":"John"},
array[1] : {"surname":"Smith"}
```

Comment: If this is the full value of `string`, it looks like you are missing wrapping it with `{ }`. Then, it becomes: `"{\"person\":\"{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}}"`.

Comment: Thank you, Sergio, for your reply. I tried your suggestion, however I still get an empty array.

Comment: A doc1.isArray() check returns false.

Comment: Based on the example, it's unclear what you're asking; there are no JSON arrays in the input string.

Comment: As I used fromJson(string.toUtf8(), &error) , it says it's QJsonParseError::UnterminatedObject.

Comment: I found another error on the string: `{\"person\":\"` that last `"` after person should not be there. `"{\"person\": {\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are no arrays present in the JSON string shown.

Arrays are denoted by `[` `]` characters. Objects are denoted by `{` `}` characters.

The JSON you showed, `"person":"{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}"`, is malformed because it has too many embedded `"` characters in it.  So lets assume that is just a typo on your part.

`"person":{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}` is a single field named `person` whose value is an object containing two named string fields, `name` and `surname`.  `QJsonDocument` can't parse this as-is, because it is expecting the JSON to be either an object or an array.

`{"person":{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}}` is an unnamed object containing the same kind of `person` field. `doc1.isObject()` returns true for this.

Either way, there is no array for `doc1.array()` to return (`doc1.isArray()` returns false).  So, if you want an array out of this data, you will have to create it yourself, eg:

```
QString string = "{\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}}";
QJsonDocument doc1 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(string.toUtf8());
if (!doc1.isObject()) {
    // handle parse error...
}

QJsonValue &person = doc1["person"];
if (person.isUndefined()) {
    // key "person" does not exist...
}


// creates an array of strings:
// array[0] = "John"
// array[1] = "Smith"
QJsonArray array = {
    person["name"],
    person["surname"]
};

or

// creates an array of objects:
// array[0] = {"name":"John"}
// array[1] = {"surname":"Smith"}
QJsonArray array = {
    QJsonObject({"name", person["name"]}),
    QJsonObject({"surname", person["surname"]})
};

// use array as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your detailed answer. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QString string = "{\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}}";

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(string.toUtf8());
QJsonObject json = doc.object();

QJsonArray jsonArray;

foreach(const QString& key, json.keys()) {

        QJsonObject Obj = json.value(key).toObject();

        foreach(const QString& key, Obj.keys()) {

            QJsonObject newObj;
            newObj[key] = Obj.value(key).toString();
            jsonArray.push_back(newObj);

        }
    }

qDebug() << "JSONARRAY" << jsonArray << endl;

// TO ACCESS YOUR ARRAY

for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++) {

    QJsonObject person = jsonArray.at(i).toObject();

    qDebug() << person;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
JSONARRAY QJsonArray([{"name":"John"},{"surname":"Smith"}]) 

QJsonObject({"name":"John"})
QJsonObject({"surname":"Smith"})
```

But I will suggest you to keep name and surname in one object so you can access and manage it properly like below:

```
QString string = "{\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\"}}";

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(string.toUtf8());
QJsonObject json = doc.object();

QJsonArray jsonArray;

foreach(const QString& key, json.keys()) {

        QJsonObject Obj = json.value(key).toObject();
        jsonArray.push_back(Obj);
    }

qDebug() << "JSONARRAY" << jsonArray << endl;

// TO ACCESS YOUR ARRAY

for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++) {

    QJsonObject person = jsonArray.at(i).toObject();

    qDebug() << person << endl;
    qDebug() << "name: " << person.value("name").toString() << endl;
    qDebug() << "surname: "<< person.value("surname").toString() << endl;

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
JSONARRAY QJsonArray([{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}]) 

QJsonObject({"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}) 

name:  "John" 

surname:  "Smith"
```